# SleekXMPP proxy issue

Tags: facebook, proxy

I am using SleekXMPP to integrate a chat bot with Facebook. When I am not behind a proxy, I get the expected behavior. But when I am behind a proxy, the connection is not established. 
I took a look at the documentation and found that I should include this part:

```
    sleekxmpp.use_proxy = True
    sleekxmpp.proxy_config = {
        'host': '10.3.100.207',
        'port': 8080,
    }
```

This gives me this final code:

```
addr = ('chat.facebook.com', 5222)
ipaddr = ('209.85.175.125',5222)

chatbot = sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP(jid,password)
sleekxmpp.use_proxy = True
sleekxmpp.proxy_config = {
    'host': '10.3.100.207',
    'port': 8080,
}
```

But it does not connect to the server. Anyone could help?

Comment: The chat API is deprecated and will be removed completely at 4/30/2015

Comment: No, there is not. I recommend that you read the changelog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_chat